# Hot and cool milk

Tags: thermodynamics

Usually I have the habit of keeping the hot milk for a while, until it becomes cool. I have noticed many a times that, drinking it, after keeping for a while, gives the mixture of hot (relatively less hot than before) and cool milk.

- Almost $3$ by $4$ (approx) part of the milk at the top, is relatively found to be hot than the last $1$ by $4$ (approx) part of the milk.

  What is the reason for upper part to be hot and lower to be cooler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convection heat transfer. Hot milk goes up from the bottom of the cup, while the milk at top download, in contact with air, gets cooler and descents to the bottom of the cup.